# Any way to merge between contains and appendTo in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, append, selector

I tried to merge between those two functions `div.contains("text")` and `appendTo()` on jQuery.

```
$( "p:contains('Powered by ')" ).appendTo(".pro");
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: more detail about the que.

Comment: I solved it https://stackoverflow.com/a/44611004/6510165

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
$( "p:contains('Powered by ')" ).addClass(".pro");
```

If you want to merge between both use `addClass()` instead of `appendTo()`.